# Jmeter:Create array, then set in property, and after that input values in array

Tags: java, arrays, jmeter

I need create in setUpThreadGroup array in BeanShell on java, after that use it in another ThreadGroup, so we need set it as property, and after that, in main ThreadGroup, store some value in array.
I have some this:

```
String [][] massive = new String[${number_of_user}][8];
props.put("array",massive);
```

In Main ThreadGroup, I use:

```
props.put("array",${__V(${double_coma}${__time(,)}${double_coma})});
System.out.println(props.get("array"));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't inline JMeter Functions and/or Variables into scripts, you should use `vars` shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instead
2. Don't use Beanshell, [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) instead

Suggested code changes:

```
String [][] massive = new String[Integer.parseInt(vars.get("number_of_user"))][8];

props.put("array", vars.get("double_coma") + System.currentTimeMillis() + vars.get("double_coma"));
```

More information on using `vars` and other JMeter API shorthands available for JSR223 Test Elements: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/)

Also be aware that in your main thread group you're **overwriting** the property rather than adding something to the array, it's unclear what you're trying to achieve but it looks very suspicious. If you want to just pass some values from one thread group to another you could consider using [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/) instead.